# Solve the recurrences, T(n)=3T(n - 1)+3

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

Can someone please help me with this recurrences?

```
T(n)=3T(n - 1)+3
```

Explanation of steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a linear recurrence with constant coefficients. Solving these is usually covered in a discrete math class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By educated guess, we can try a constant value, let `t`.

```
t = 3t + 3
```

is solved by `t = -3/2`.

Now consider `U(n) = T(n) + 3/2`. The recurrence turns to

```
U(n) - 3/2 = 3U(n-1) - 9/2 + 3
```

or

```
U(n) = 3U(n-1).
```

Obviously,

```
U(n) = U(0) 3^n.
```